# What does this netcat output mean?

Tags: networking

I want to telnet into my locally running VM which has a dictd service running on port 2628, when I issue my nc -v command though I get the following:

```
$ nc -v localhost 2628
nc: connectx to localhost port 2628 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif lo0
    src 127.0.0.1 port 63929
    dst 127.0.0.1 port 2628
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to localhost port 2628 [tcp/dict] succeeded!
```

Why is there a connection refused and then a connection succeeded later on? What does this mean and why won't it accept my connection when I just do: `telnet localhost 2628`?

Answer (score 15):

There are a few dozen versions of netcat available, but this is likely because:

1. You have 2 entries for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`. One for IPv4, another for IPv6.
2. The daemon is only listening on one protocol (likely IPv4).
3. The client is first connecting via the protocol the daemon isn't listening on, and then trying the one that it is.

For example:

```
$ grep localhost /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

$ nc -4 -l -p 9000 -s 127.0.0.1     
nc: listening on 127.0.0.1 9000 ...


$ nc localhost 9000
nc: cannot connect to localhost (::1) 9000 [9000]: Connection refused
nc: localhost (127.0.0.1) 9000 [9000] open
nc: using stream socket
```

Comment: Ok, if this is what is happening though, how do I fix it?

Comment: Fix any of the 3 numbered items. 1) remove one of the entries from `/etc/hosts`. 2) make the daemon listen on both protocols. 3) force the client to connect using the other protocol.